# top and bottom pagination jQuery

Tags: jquery, pagination, navigation

I already made a jsfiddle for demo purposes: https://jsfiddle.net/b8gmqx9p/2/

Here's the jQuery code:

```
(function($){

   $.fn.customPaginate = function(options)
   {
       var paginationContainer = this;
       var itemsToPaginate;


       var defaults = {

            itemsPerPage : 3

       };

       var settings = {};

       $.extend(settings, defaults, options);

       var itemsPerPage = settings.itemsPerPage;

       itemsToPaginate = $(settings.itemsToPaginate);
       var numberOfPaginationLinks = Math.ceil((itemsToPaginate.length / itemsPerPage));

       $("<ul></ul>").prependTo(paginationContainer);

       for(var index = 0; index < numberOfPaginationLinks; index++)
       {
            paginationContainer.find("ul").append("<li>"+ (index+1) + "</li>");
       }

       itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + (itemsPerPage - 1)  + ")").hide();

       paginationContainer.find("ul li").on('click', function(){

            var linkNumber = $(this).text();

            var itemsToHide = itemsToPaginate.filter(":lt(" + ((linkNumber-1) * itemsPerPage)  + ")");
            $.merge(itemsToHide, itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + ((linkNumber * itemsPerPage) - 1)  + ")"));
            itemsToHide.hide();

            var itemsToShow = itemsToPaginate.not(itemsToHide);
            itemsToShow.show("300");

           $(this).addClass('pagination_active').siblings().removeClass('pagination_active');

       });

   } }(jQuery));  (function($){

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".pagination").customPaginate({

        itemsToPaginate : ".pagination_show"

    });

}); })(jQuery)
```

I would like to have the navigation bar both on top and bottom and I would like both elements to show the active page. For now it does not show that the first page is active when you initially open the site (or see the demo). When you click on "2" it gets yellow as it should be. But I would like to have the class set to active on "1" when you initially open the site. And I would like to show on both bottom and top navigation.

Secondly,

I would like to add a "previous" and "next" button to the navigation bar, which should contain a function to either move to the next (e.g. from page 2 to 3) or to move to the previous page (e.g. from page 3 to 2).

I appreciate your help with that! I'm just no good in jQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want-

```js
( function($) {

                    $.fn.customPaginate = function(options) {
                        var paginationContainer = this;
                        var itemsToPaginate;

                        var defaults = {

                            itemsPerPage : 3

                        };

                        var settings = {};

                        $.extend(settings, defaults, options);

                        var itemsPerPage = settings.itemsPerPage;

                        itemsToPaginate = $(settings.itemsToPaginate);
                        var numberOfPaginationLinks = Math.ceil((itemsToPaginate.length / itemsPerPage));

                        
                        $("<ul></ul>").prependTo(paginationContainer);
                        
                        for(var pagerEle=0; pagerEle<paginationContainer.length; pagerEle++){                            
                            for (var index = 0; index < numberOfPaginationLinks; index++) {                            
                                paginationContainer.eq(pagerEle).find("ul").append("<li>" + (index + 1) + "</li>");
                                if(index == 0){
                                    paginationContainer.eq(pagerEle).find("ul li").eq(0).addClass('pagination_active');
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        

                        itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + (itemsPerPage - 1) + ")").hide();

                        paginationContainer.find("ul li").on('click', function(e) {

                            var linkNumber = $(this).text();

                            var itemsToHide = itemsToPaginate.filter(":lt(" + ((linkNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage) + ")");
                            $.merge(itemsToHide, itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + ((linkNumber * itemsPerPage) - 1) + ")"));
                            itemsToHide.hide();

                            var itemsToShow = itemsToPaginate.not(itemsToHide);
                            itemsToShow.show("300");

                            $(this).addClass('pagination_active').siblings().removeClass('pagination_active');
                            pagerCurIndex = $(this).index();
                            
                            for(var pagerEle=0; pagerEle<paginationContainer.length; pagerEle++){                            
                                paginationContainer.eq(pagerEle).find("ul li").eq(pagerCurIndex).addClass('pagination_active').siblings().removeClass('pagination_active');
                            }
                            

                        });

                    }
                }(jQuery));

            (function($) {

                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $(".pagination").customPaginate({

                        itemsToPaginate : ".pagination_show"

                    });

                });

            })(jQuery)
```

```css
ul.products_erweitert li {
width: 221px;
margin-right: 0.5%;
margin-left: 0.5%;
margin-bottom: 0.4%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
}

.asa2_uhrenshop_main_container {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; margin-bottom: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height:350px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.12),0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.24);
}

.asa2_uhrenshop_main_container:hover {
    border: 1px solid #db9f1e;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.28);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.28);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.14),0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.28);
}

.also_a_test {
    background-color:#00CD00;
}

.best_test {
    background-color:#8A2BE2
}

.pagination li
{ display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #db9f1e !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
margin-right: 3px;
}

.pagination li:hover
{
    background: #db9f1e;
  border-color: #db9f1e !important;
  color: #fff !important;
transition: all 0.5s;
}

.pagination_active {
background: #db9f1e;
border-color: #db9f1e !important;
color: #fff !important;
}

.pagination ul
{
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.pagination {
margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination"></div>
<ul class="products_erweitert"><li class="pagination_show"><div class="asa2_uhrenshop_main_container"> This is a test</div>
        </li>
         
<li class="pagination_show">        
<div class="asa2_uhrenshop_main_container"> This is a test</div>
        </li>
    
<li class="pagination_show">        
<div class="asa2_uhrenshop_main_container"> This is a test</div>
        </li>

<li class="pagination_show">        
<div class="asa2_uhrenshop_main_container also_a_test"> This is also a test</div>
        </li>
    <li class="pagination_show">        
<div class="asa2_uhrenshop_main_container also_a_test"> This is also a test</div>
        </li>
    <li class="pagination_show">        
<div class="asa2_uhrenshop_main_container also_a_test"> This is also a test</div>
        </li>
    <li class="pagination_show">        
<div class="asa2_uhrenshop_main_container best_test"> This is the best test</div>
        </li>
    <li class="pagination_show">        
<div class="asa2_uhrenshop_main_container best_test"> This is the best test</div>
        </li>
    <li class="pagination_show">        
<div class="asa2_uhrenshop_main_container best_test"> This is the best test</div>
        </li>

</ul><div class="pagination"></div>
```

Comment: Hi there, this is perfect! Thank you so much - it worked very well! Your efforts are deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This example will be help you http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-jquery-pagination-system/. You can see the demo and could download it

If you want to set the first page selected you must to use

```
for(var index = 0; index < numberOfPaginationLinks; index++) 
{     
    if(index==0) 
    { 
         paginationContainer.find("ul").append("<li class='pagination_active'>"+ (index+1) + "</li>"); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
         paginationContainer.find("ul").append("<li>"+ (index+1) + "</li>");   
    }
}

In the line 20 of your js
```

Comment: I found that example, but I have two things to consider: first, I would rather stick to my code snippet and secondly, your example doesn't have the navigation on both top and bottom of the content. Could you help me with my code? https://jsfiddle.net/b8gmqx9p/2/

Comment: If you want to set the first page selected you must to use  for(var index = 0; index < numberOfPaginationLinks; index++)
           {
               if(index==0)
               {
                   paginationContainer.find("ul").append("<li class='pagination_active'>"+ (index+1) + "</li>");
               }
               else
               {
                paginationContainer.find("ul").append("<li>"+ (index+1) + "</li>");
               }
           } 

In the line 20 of your js

Comment: ok thank you so far, but it still doesn't fix the issue with the first page not being shown as active when you initially open the site...your can see it in the fiddle - number 1 on the navigation is not active https://jsfiddle.net/b8gmqx9p/6/

Comment: Try to change the JS in the url and then click on Run button at the top, then you can see that first page is activated. It works for me

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "Try to change the JS in the url"? I cannot find a "JS" in the URL :(